# Windows Phone 7 Scoring provider

Tags: windows-phone-7, scoring

I am not too sure if this question is suited for this forum. If not, please let me know and I'll delete this.

I wanted to figure out the "easiest" way of keeping online score for a game or quiz on Windows Phone 7. Currently, I am not looking for things like Achievements etc. I know XBOX live provides a lot of stuff on these grounds, but it is not open for all.

I want to submit the score, and maintain the top 200 (may be less) odd scores. I am too lazy to write my own services and host it and go through the full maintenance cycle for that scoring system. Can someone point out some really good and easy to use + reliable services that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product offered by [Mogade](http://www.mogade.com/) has a lot of the features you have asked for:

- **Real time stats**
- Achievements
- **Logging**
- Javascript leaderboards & Facebook pages
- **Always free**
- No branding requirements

It's a very streamlined library where you only need to set up the bare essentials to get it working as all of the heavy lifting is managed for you automatically, allowing you to focus more time on the development of your game.

**briansoli** has written a [fairly straightforward tutorial](http://briansolli.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/online-leaderboard-for-your-wp7-game/) on how to get a leaderboard working with in a Windows Phone 7 game.

I hope you find this useful, let us know how you get on with it!

Comment: Now they stopped the service :( any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Microosft have just released a new toolkit called the Windows Azure Toolkit for Social Games.  This should help you out with quite a bit.

Have a look at this Cloud Cover Show, [Episode 52 - Tankster and the Windows Azure Toolkit for Social Games](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-52-Tankster-and-the-Windows-Azure-Toolkit-for-Social-Games)

The toolkit enables unique capabilities for social gaming prerequisites, such as storing user profiles, maintaining leader boards, in-app purchasing, and more. The toolkit also comes complete with reusable server side code and documentation, as well as Tankster, a new proof-of-concept game built with HTML5

Comment: Is it free or paid or free trial?